# How do I list Wine drive letter mappings?

Tags: wine

I've been handed a batchfile that operates on a drive letter, a USB-drive. I know Wine has a number of drives set up for me; besides the standard `c:` and `z:` drives there is also `[d-g]:`, but what do they point to?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the complete list of mappings by listing `~/.wine/dosdevices`:

```
$ ls -l ~/.wine/dosdevices/
totalt 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rovanion rovanion 10 feb 27 11:33 c: -> ../drive_c/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rovanion rovanion 10 feb 27 11:41 com1 -> /dev/ttyS0
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rovanion rovanion  9 feb 27 11:33 d:: -> /dev/sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rovanion rovanion  8 feb 27 11:33 e:: -> /dev/sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rovanion rovanion  9 feb 27 11:33 f:: -> /dev/sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rovanion rovanion  9 feb 27 11:33 g:: -> /dev/sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rovanion rovanion  1 feb 27 11:33 z: -> //
```

You can then use `lsblk` to map these device paths to your understanding of what these devices actually are:

```
$ lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,uuid
NAME        MOUNTPOINT                         LABEL                      SIZE UUID
...
sda                                            Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS amd64  28,8G 2022-08-31-07-21-46-00
├─sda1                                         Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS amd64   3,6G 2022-08-31-07-21-46-00
├─sda2                                                                    3,9M 54C5-9C6C
└─sda3                                         writable                  25,2G e841322e-9e12-4fc2-88e2-455e06c5101a
nvme0n1                                                                 476,9G 
├─nvme0n1p1 /boot/efi                          SYSTEM                     260M AE94-0B27
├─nvme0n1p2                                                                16M 
├─nvme0n1p3                                                              84,1G 
├─nvme0n1p4                                    WinRE_DRV                    2G B66296D4629698A7
├─nvme0n1p5 /                                  Ubuntu 22.10              78,2G 33fa3dc2-405b-4dfc-a085-c09db7ed756b
├─nvme0n1p6 /home                              Home                     297,5G 29fbfed8-cde6-48dc-9d47-44a689f5b61c
└─nvme0n1p7                                    Ubuntu 20.04              14,9G 6dd45223-f09d-47d9-bde1-5ca960612b21
```